# calling multiple products with multiple prices, price selected by user

Tags: php, sql

This is my SQL structure:

TABLE= products

```
id_products - title_products - price_products - id_stock
1           - Teddy          - 15             - 1  
2           - Balloon        - 10             - 1
```

right now i have this form with multiple products and this is how i send the data to the other page:

INPUT IS INSIDE A LOOP so multiple products are loaded from SQL DB, ID's are sent in a array to next page:

```
<input name="prod[<?=$id?>]" id="prod[<?=$id?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$id?>">
<input name="prod[<?=$id?>]" id="prod[<?=$id?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$id?>">
<input name="prod[<?=$id?>]" id="prod[<?=$id?>]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$id?>">
```

I CALL THIS SQL QUERY LOOP IN NEXT PAGE:

```
$sql="select * from table where id_stock<>'0' and id_products IN (".$ids.")";
```

So what it does is send all IDS from selected products, and in the next page it gets all the info from those IDS with the IN function in SQL.

---

Now what i want to achieve is this:

**SQL STRUCTURE IDEA #1**

TABLE= products

```
id_products - title_products - price_products - id_stock
1           - Teddy          - 15,20          - 1  
2           - Balloon        - 10,15          - 1
```

**SQL STRUCTURE IDEA #2**

TABLE= products

```
id_products - title_products - id_stock
1           - Teddy          - 1  
2           - Balloon        - 1
```

TABLE= prices

```
id_price_products - id_products - title_products - price_products
1                 - 1           - Small          - 15
2                 - 1           - Big            - 20
3                 - 2           - Small          - 10
4                 - 2           - Big            - 15
```

**FORM SELECT:**

```
echo '<select  id="prod['.$id.']" name="prod['.$id.']" >';
foreach($price_ex as $price) {
    echo'<option value="'.$price_id.'">'.$price.'</option>';
}                                   
echo'</select>';
```

But i don't know how to do in next page because before there was only 1 price now user has multiple price options, so the SQL should get the info from the selected IDS and selected price from user.

I would appreciate any help on how to resolve this,  tx.

Comment: The question becomes less clear as I read toward the bottom.  Can you explain `prices` -- `Small`, `Big`?

Comment: i want products to have multiple prices so the user can select the price they want and each price comes with a title, SMALL=15, BIG=20

Comment: BTW: Your `<input>` has three attributes that are identical: `prod`.`$id`.  Suggest you give every input in this group the same `name` without the ID, like `name="prod"`.  I imagine you will have easier handling on the next page.

Comment: the $ID identifies each product ID that it gets from the DB

Comment: Thanks for presenting your code.  I think we need more of the "user story".  What is the process, screen by screen, when I buy a product?